# New-AzureStorageContext : Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed

Tags: powershell, azure

I am getting below error in the following Azure Powershell cmdlet. I have verifed the Accountname and Key it is fine. What else may go wrong?

```
$storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext –StorageAccountName $storage_AccountName –StorageAccountKey $storage_Key
```

> New-AzureStorageContext : Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.

Comment: can you run this PS command `Get-AzureRmStorageAccount`? Which version of your Azure PowerShell? Please run this script to check it. `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh`

Comment: I am having Azure 3.4.0

Answer (score 0):

I could run the command without any errors, please follow the below steps and let us know the status

1.`Login-AzureRmAccount`

2.`$storage_Key = "h2+od6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx9C3z3oe+uJciXLaaS6exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxdy+n6A=="`

3.`$storageContext=New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName “storage account name” -StorageAccountKey $storage_Key`

Answer (score 0):

> I am having Azure 3.4.0

For now, the latest version is 4.3.1, maybe we should upgrade your PowerShell.

We can download the installer [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/download/v4.3.1-August2017/azure-powershell.4.3.1.msi).

More information about Azure PowerShell release, please refer to this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases).